# JQuery + Ajax send username with dots?

Tags: jquery, ajax, input

I'm trying to send a username with dots through ajax but I can't find a way to do it successfully, this is my code:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'access.php',
    data: {username: $('#'+username.replace(".", "\\.")).show()).val(), password: $('#password').val()},
    success: function(data){
        // use data
    }
});
```

In my html form my username input would be something like "mike.smith"

Hope you can help me with this, thanks in advance! :)

Comment: Does it not work without trying to escape the dot? You also have one too many `)`

Comment: Your code makes no sense.  It looks like you're confusing the value with the ID.

Comment: @SLaks I wish I could upvote 10 times lol

Comment: Sorry guys I'm newbie at JQuery and Ajax I need to work harder :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'access.php',
    data: { username: $('#username').val(), password: $('#password').val()},
    success: function(data) { 
        // ... 
    }
}
```

At least that's what I'm guessing you're trying to do

Comment: Yes this is what I'm trying!! Thanks a lot!

Comment: @PhillipSchmidt: You should not call `encodeURIComponent`; jQuery will correctly assemble a POST payload.

Comment: @SLaks good point. I was caught up on the whole "with dots" thing and I didn't stop to think that that wasn't actually part of the problem.